# Building app on ios when using firebase-auth causes a problem with flutter

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am making an app that uses firestore and firebase_auth and this works fine when using android, but when I build it on ios, it causes an array of problems:

```
 error: incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(FIRUser *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to
    parameter of type 'FIRAuthDataResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)')
                                                 completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 note: passing argument to parameter 'completion' here
                      completion:(nullable FIRAuthDataResultCallback)completion;
error: incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(FIRUser *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to
    parameter of type 'FIRAuthDataResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)')
                                                 completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
note: passing argument to parameter 'completion' here
                      completion:(nullable FIRAuthDataResultCallback)completion;
 error: incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(FIRUser *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to
    parameter of type 'FIRAuthDataResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)')
                                                 completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 note: passing argument to parameter 'completion' here
                      completion:(nullable FIRAuthDataResultCallback)completion;
warning: 'fetchProvidersForEmail:completion:' is deprecated: Please use
    fetchSignInMethodsForEmail:completion: for Objective-C or fetchSignInMethods(forEmail:completion:) for Swift instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            fetchProvidersForEmail:email
note: 'fetchProvidersForEmail:completion:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("Please use fetchSignInMethodsForEmail:completion: for Objective-C or "
error: incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSError * _Nullable __strong)' to parameter of
    type 'FIRAuthDataResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)')
                              completion:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
note: passing argument to parameter 'completion' here
                              completion:(nullable FIRAuthDataResultCallback)completion;
error: incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSError * _Nullable __strong)' to parameter of
    type 'FIRAuthDataResultCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable __strong, NSError * _Nullable __strong)')
                              completion:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
```

I am using firebase_auth 0.6.6 if this information is needed.

Comment: The app just will not build and these errors come up in the command line. However, the app will work just fine on Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. For some reason, this occurred for me because I have firestore and firebase_auth together in my project, so for android, I was using one version of both plugins, but I need to have different versions of those plugins when dealing with iOS.

Comment: What are the versions you used? Still am facing this issue.